# Puppeteer Web Scraper runs on local machine only but fails to deploy as Google Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I have built a simple scraper with Puppeteer which I can run locally on my machine, but when I deploy it as a Google Cloud function, it's not working. The only error message I get from the Google Cloud Logs is:

> Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in
> the user code.

Here are the steps I follow to deploy it the function; code is further below.
(Note: I'm outlining the process of zipping the files; I have tried the Cloud Function inline editor as well but am receiving the same error.)

1. Run npm install
2. Run zip -r my-app.zip *
3. Create new Google Cloud function
   -- Name 'newFunction'
   -- Memory: 1gb
   -- Runtime: Node.js 14
   -- Entry point: scrapeFunction
4. Upload Zip

**index.js**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const { BigQuery } = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

async function scrapeFunction() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('<URL>', {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0});
  await page.waitForSelector('span.text');
  const info = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.querySelector('span.text').innerText;
  });
  console.log(info); 

  // Write results to BigQuery table
  const bigqueryClient = new BigQuery();
  const dataset = bigqueryClient.dataset('xxx');
  const table = dataset.table('yyy');
  const rows = [{ info: info }];
  await table.insert(rows);

  await browser.close();
}

scrapeFunction();
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "newFunction",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/bigquery": "^6.1.0",
    "puppeteer": "^19.7.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're following the instructions for building Cloud Functions.  Firstly, the declared function needs to be exported.  Secondly, you're not supposed to call that function at the top level.  GCF will call it for you when the triggering event happens (which you haven't shown us here).  I suggest following a quickstart or other sample that Google provides to learn how the product works, then modify that meet your needs.

Comment: There needs to be a lot of non-standard system libraries installed. You need to follow a guide specifically for puppeteer and GCF. Even then there's a chance the website will block traffic from data centers.

Comment: Great, thanks for that. Naively I thought if I can get it to run on my local machine, the deployment to GCF will be a walk in the park :sigh: